# Top or Sample N of subgroups in Teradata in a large data set ("No Spool Space" error)

Tags: teradata, data-partitioning

I've tried several routes to getting the 10 records from each subset of a large dataset and the best I can do is querying each subgroup explicitly in the query.

My first attempt from the (Teradata community help [website](https://support.teradata.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=2a5807671b97fb00682ca8233a4bcb0c)) was this:

```
Select * FROM Table Qualify Row_number() Over (partition by date order by column) between 1 and 10;
```

I wanted this to work because I didn't want to manually go and harvest the partitions, but I run out of spool space when I try that.  In the same forum there's this solution

```
  FROM TheTable

SAMPLE WHEN TheDate = '2014-01-01' THEN 10

            WHEN TheDate = '2014-2-01' THEN 10

...

END;
```

It works, but obviously is not dynamic to the dataset contents.  Can I get a solution that is dynamic for large data sets?

Comment: Your first attempt is how I would do this.  Solving spool space errors in a forum like this is pretty difficult, I'd suggest working with your DBAs.

Comment: Instead of ROW_NUMBER which requires ORDER BY, maybe try `SUM(1) OVER (PARTITION BY TheDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)` to eliminate the sort. And if the rows are large, consider selecting just some key field or fields rather than SELECT * then JOIN the keys back to the original table